# Files uploaded onto web server does not contain actual file data

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, http-post

I am trying to create a simple Cakephp 2.5.1 app that accepts file upload. I am using the file uploader plugin provided in http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader. I followed the instructions in the website and got it installed and it seems to work fine.

The code below is added to the model.php. There is a column 'picture' in the model table.

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        // Do not copy all these settings, it's merely an example
        'picture' => array(
            'nameCallback' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'tempDir' => TMP,
            'uploadDir' => '',
            'transportDir' => '',
            'finalPath' => '',
            'dbColumn' => '',
            'metaColumns' => array(),
            'defaultPath' => '',
            'overwrite' => false,
            'stopSave' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'transforms' => array(),
            'transformers' => array(),
            'transport' => array(),
            'transporters' => array(),
            'curl' => array()
        )
    )
);
```

In the associated ctp file, I have the following code;

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

I managed to upload an image file SSSS.jpg to the webserver. However, the strange thing is that the uploaded image file is a tiny file which contains the HTTP POST information in text, not the actual image data. The file contents looks something like this;

```
_method=POST&_method=POST&data%5BUpload%5D%5Bpicture%5D=SSSS.jpg
```

Can someone tell me what are the possible things that have gone wrong? Thank you.

EDIT: I just noticed in Chrome debugging that under the HTTP POST method, the file sent was of type `text/html`. Is this a problem? If yes, how do I change the type to `image/jpg` ?

Comment: You used multipart type on your html where you send the file?

Comment: I am not sure. In Cakephp, the view helper does things in the background. Let me check first.

Comment: Also verify that the name of the field is the same as it is on the upload handler on your cakephp.

Comment: Below form code does contain `enctype="multipart/form-data" `



`<form action="/project-cp251/uploads/add" id="UploadAddForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div><div class="input file"><label for="UploadPicture">Picture</label><input type="file" name="data[Upload][picture]"  id="UploadPicture"/></div><div class="submit"><input  type="submit" value="Submit"/></div></form>`

Comment: @eddwinpaz: Could the problem be caused by the file type that is being sent in the HTTP Post is `text/html` and not `image/jpg`?

Comment: Do a print_r($_FILES) and see if the file it's getting to the server.

Comment: @eddwinpaz: name of field is `picture`. It corresponds to the one in upload hander.

Comment: Is data[upload][picture] set on your cakephp script?

Comment: @eddwinpaz: Is it correct to add print_r($_FILES) in the controller?

Comment: The problem is on the server side not on the clients side html form just sends the data.

Comment: @eddwinpaz: I think data[upload][picture] is automatically generated by the Cakephp view helper.

Comment: Print_r is just to see what you are getting.

Comment: In your settings I see you are not setting a upload dir and other basic settings

Comment: The upload dir is by default set at webroot/upload/files.

Comment: You are getting empty images with the name of the file you uploaded right?

Comment: Change the default path to another folder and set the proper file permission

Comment: Change file to File/image

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file/image'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));
```

To the following syntax

```
echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file/image'));
```

Sample Code:

```
echo $form->labelTag('File/image', 'Image');
echo $html->file('File/image');
```

Comment: Thanks! Verified and marked as the correct answer. But there is one more problem. After I change to `'file/image'`, the input field becomes a textbox where I have to enter the full path of the file. When it was `'type' => 'file'`, it is a button which I can click and a dialog box appears for me to select the file. Funny thing though was that the full path did not appear, only the name of the file appeared. Wondered whether that is the source of the problem.

Comment: Read this http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/uploading_files_and_images_with_cakephp